# Header field not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers - Node/Express/KeystoneJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, keystonejs

I have CORS issue and spend a lot of time trying to figure it out, so I decide to ask a question here. I have keystone app on a subdomain to the domain where is my angular 5 app. On localhost everything works ok but, but when I put my files to the server and try open my angular app I get this error:

> Failed to load http://xxxxxxxx.com/label: Request header
>   field params is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
>   preflight response.

I have added this lines to my keystone.js file:

```
keystone.set('cors allow origin', true);
keystone.set('cors allow methods', true);
keystone.set('cors allow headers', true);
```

And this line in routes/index.js:

```
app.all('/*', keystone.middleware.cors);
```

And I tried add this to routes/index.js:

```
app.options('/*', function(req, res) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST');
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
```

But I still get the same error. Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: And everything is from same origin? Can you show the error you are getting, that would help identify the issue a bit more.

Comment: No, everything isn't from the same origin. I have api (keystonejs) on subdomain to domain where is my angular app. I added error to my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: No, that's not duplicate of thread you post, because my question is about baked in keystonejs cors module which doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install this package  https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors and manage your CORS domains.

**basic usage**

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Comment: Yeah, that works fine! I don't understand why cors module backed in keystone doesn't work. Thank you for your answer! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well the error message says it all (admittdely not very clearly) - **Request header field params is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.** - this means that there is a request header called `params` which isn't included in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers (ACAH) response header.

Change the ACAH to be this:

```
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, params");
```

and you should be fine.

Not that adding a separate package won't **also** solve the problem, but you don't **need** to add a new package to get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Keystone.js and I am editing /routes/middleware.js by adding the below lines at the end of file:

```
/*
 * CORS
 */
exports.setCors = function (req,res,next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*.*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
}
```